# Word for "letter or letter-like character"?

Tags: single-word-requests, technical

Is there a word for a "letter or letter-like character" in a writing system? With that I mean a grapheme that is not a number, punctuation, special symbol or space, but a letter (alphabet), consonant-vowel-unit (abugida), syllabogram (syllabrary) or a logogram (logographic writing system). Or in other words: A unit of text that is formed by a character of the Unicode category "L", maybe followed by combining marks "M".

edit:
I need the word for a user interface; it should be understood by the average user.

edit2:
To clarify the purpose: I have a system that learns word structures from user input. In the documentation I explain an algorithm that does some stuff with the input. This is the sentence:

> By default all letters and letter-like characters (such as the syllable symbols of a syllabary like Japanese Katakana) are included, everything else (such as numbers and punctuation) is excluded [from the alphabet].

Comment: I don't think there is a word for this. Maybe you should label the field after what its *purpose* is. Maybe you could elaborate on that?

Comment: I don't even think _the average user_ is going to understand it, no matter which word you use.

Comment: Frankly, the fact that you are excluding numbers (or more exactly *digits*) from your definition, makes it completely arbitrary and therefore very unlikely to match any existing denomination. For an example of why that is, take the case of Japanese/Chinese, were digits *are* kanji/hanzi and vice-versa. Where does the kanji for '5' go in your definition?

Comment: @Dave It's not arbitrary. That's how Unicode structures characters. But logographic writing systems are a fringe case for that algorithm anyway, so it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [The Go programming Language - Package unicode](http://golang.org/pkg/unicode/)

> func IsLetter(rune int)
>
> bool IsLetter reports whether the rune is a letter (category L).

I therefore suggest the category word OP seeks is simply **letter**.

Comment: Yes, Unicode calls it "letter", but to me it feels wrong to use the term for characters of non-alphabetic scripts, especially for syllabograms and logograms.

Comment: If you want a word that excludes punctuation marks, digits, etc., I think you'll just have to accept it feeling wrong. Once you start looking for "universal" terminology that works with all languages and transcription symbol sets, words like *consonant* and *vowel* are pretty useless, but *letter* still just about has meaning.

Answer (score 9):

A *glyph* is a symbol that is an element of the language you are writing in. There term *pseudo-glyph* denotes marks that should look like an element of the language but are not.

Comment: I think a glyph would be *any* type of character, including punctuation or numbers.

Comment: I thought of "glyph" too, but wouldn't that include everything, even dingbats?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you talk about elements of written words, regardless of how they are scoped (letter, consonant-vowel, syllable, word).

I think there's no word for this purpose and you'll have to introduce your terms.

Something like *L-glyph*, and define it.

<sub>Note: I am not linguist and this is pure linguistic. I suggest you to try the question on [linguistics](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com) as well.</sub>